# I want to make a app in Python and have the front end in HTML and CSS

Tags: python, html, css, user-interface

Is there anyway I can make a app. With the back end in python. And the front end in HTML and css

I've tried some of the GUI libraries for python and they all are not that good

Edit: Found what I wanted https://github.com/IanTerzo/Neutron

Comment: Have you tried using something like Django https://www.djangoproject.com/ or Flask? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/ They are frameworks built for backend (on Python, of course)

Comment: These look like they're all made for webpages. I want to make a desktop application

Comment: Something like electron but python

Comment: Ahh, in that case, have you tried something like Tkinter https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?

Comment: Yeah I have but I want to use HTML and CSS to make the front end

Comment: I guess you could go along with using electron and python (python backend), you could read more about it here: https://www.fyears.org/2015/06/electron-as-gui-of-python-apps.html

Comment: https://pyscript.net/

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have built-in mobile development capabilities, but there are packages you can use to create mobile applications, like Kivy, PyQt, or even Beeware's Toga library. These libraries are all major players in the Python mobile space.